# How to Set Text to the text view in Fragment Activity programmatically?

Tags: android

I have a Fragment Activity i need to set Text to the text view in that Activity,when i am using following code getting null pointer exception.
can any other approach is there to set data for text view .

```
public class Introduction extends Fragment  {
     TextView txt;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

         View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_introduction, container, false);
         txt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.officeheader);
         return v;

        }
    public void setText(String text){

        txt.setText(text);
    }
    }
```

and in My Fragment Activity class :

```
frgManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
         frgManager.beginTransaction()

        . replace(R.id.fragmentoffice, introduction,"introduction")
         .commit();

        introduction.setText(" Office Coffee that will \n have everyone talking ");
```

Comment: i think you should do that in OnCreateView method of fragment.

Comment: i need to set Text from Fragment Activity class

Comment: pass the text with bundle and get in the fragment

Comment: but after all you are going to fragment right? so you should do like @NIDHIGABA said.

Answer (score 2):

set string in bundle

```
Bundle bundl = new Bundle();
bundl.putString("Text", text);
introduction.setArguments(bundl)
frgManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
frgManager.beginTransaction()
. replace(R.id.fragmentoffice, introduction,"introduction")
.commit();
```

get text from bundle

```
public class Introduction extends Fragment  {
     TextView txt;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
String str = getArguments().getString("Text");
         View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_introduction, container, false);
         txt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.officeheader);
         setText(str);
         return v;

        }
    public void setText(String text){

        txt.setText(text);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write introduction constructor ,which contain a parameter Type String ,
and on the onCreateView ,you can initialize the textivew and settext